# Loop through filter records

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through filter rows but loop go through all columns and then move to next row.

```
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim rngTar As Range
Dim lRow, lCol As Integer

Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Datewise")

lRow = wsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = wsMain.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rngTar = wsMain.Range(wsMain.Cells(1, 1), wsMain.Cells(lRow, lCol))

wsMain.AutoFilterMode = False
rngTar.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="=KEEP"

For Each rng In rngTar.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    MsgBox wsMain.Range("Q" & rng.Row).Value, , wsMain.Range("R" & rng.Row).Value
Next rng
```

If I have 18 columns then above loop will move next row after 18 times loop in for next

Comment: Do you want to loop only through a particular column? If yes, then set the `rngTar` to only include that last column, for example `Set rngTar = wsMain.Range(wsMain.Cells(1, 1), wsMain.Cells(lRow, 1))` for column 1

Comment: Try to look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249555/excel-vba-loop-through-visible-filtered-rows

Comment: After changing he scope of range my purpose is solve. _**wsMain.Cells(1, 16), wsMain.Cells(lRow, 16)**_ Thnx.